# Getting error at clicking a list item C#, Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to get an element clicked, the element is in a list, i have successfully opened the list but upon clicking  its generating exception. I tried xpath, id and others but its not working.

```
action.MoveToElement(client.Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@id,'notescontrol-action_bar_add_command')]"))).Click();

xrmApp.ThinkTime(5000);

action.MoveToElement(client.Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text()),'appointment']"))).Click();
```

Comment: What exception does it generate? What is the error message?

Comment: Element not found, no such element. this type of exception it generates.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the information for the exception. Also please let us know which line of code is throwing the exception. You will also need to include the relevant HTML that Selenium is attempting to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had trouble finding elements by text before, using linkText, XPath and others (it was never consistent). I would advise to:
(for example, if you want a button with text "notescontrol")

- Get a list of elements by tag name "button":

  ```
  IWebElement myElement;
  IList<IWebElement> listOfButtons = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("button"));
  ```
- Then iterate over the list, and find the button you want by checking the text:

  ```
  foreach(IWebElement element in listOfButtons){
     if(element.contains("notescontrol")){
        myElement = element;
     }
  }
  ```